# register_activation_hook in construct doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I have an question about register_activation_hook in construct.

I have read, that this should be possible, but I don't know, currently nothing will be written to the error_log (for debugging).

Look here, the author say it should work http://www.plulz.com/how-to-create-a-plugin-for-wordpress

Here's my code

```
<?php
abstract class LW_Capability{
    const NAME = 'Capability';

    public function __construct(){
        register_activation_hook(
            __FILE__,
            array(
                $this,
                'activate'
            )
        );

        register_deactivation_hook(
            __FILE__,
            array(
                $this,
                'deactivate'
            )
        );
    }

    public function activate(){
        error_log('LW_Capability->activate');
    }

    public function deactivate(){
        error_log('LW_Capability->deactivate');
    }


}

class CapabilityEditRessource extends LW_Capability{
    const NAME = 'EditRessource';
}
?>
```

What do I do wrong? If I add an "die('parent')" to the LW_Capability, it will die. The Plugin can't be activated then (WP Blocks because of output).

Anyone here who does somthing similar?

Would be happy to hear from you.

Regards, 
 Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
register_activation_hook(
        __FILE__,
        array(
            $this,
            'activate'
        )
    );

    register_deactivation_hook(
        __FILE__,
        array(
            $this,
            'deactivate'
        )
    );
```

could just be used in the main-file of the plugin ^^

I modifyed it to

```
register_activation_hook(
    __FILE__,
    array(
        $MyPluginInstance,
        'activate'
    )
);

register_deactivation_hook(
    __FILE__,
    array(
        $MyPluginInstance,
        'deactivate'
    )
);
```

And this functions calls manually the register / unregister-functions of the capability-class

Comment: "solve"... it's a wordpress-restriction, that you have to use register_activation_hook in the main-file of the plugin (where also is the plugin-comment placed). it's more or less a workaround.